# .NET Core produce single dll

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a console app with this `test.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract> 
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.11.0-dev-01380" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I launch `dotnet publish` these files are created:

```
test.dll
test.pdb
test.runtimeconfig.json
Serilog.dll
Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll
```

How can I produce a single `test.dll` that contain all others dlls?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this works with .net core, but back in the day we had: https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge

Comment: You seemed to have missed the all important "PublishSingleFile" and "SelfContained" options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview